# Get current view. Reload view later

Tags: angularjs

I implemented a back button that allows the user to go back to the previous view. However, I only want this back button to affect a particular "String of Links".

Example: Say I have a side bar with three links and a main view like so,

```
______________________
view8 |               |
view1 |   MAIN VIEW   |
view9 |               |
______|_______________|
```

The view1 link pops view1 into the main view. view1 then contains a link to view2 then view2 then contains a link to view3 and so on. We will call this our "String of Links".

The view9 link pops view9 into the main view. Currently, on view9, there is a back button that will take you back to the previous page. That back button uses `window.history.back();` to route to the last view.

The problem I am having is that if the user first clicks view8 then clicks view9, the back button on view9 will send the user back to view8. But I want the user to go back to the last view on the "String of Links".

How would I go about saving a view on the "String of Links" and then later calling that view and loading it into the main view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use angular's [routeProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) or my personal favorite [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing), which would allow you to enable browser history in the way that you describe.

The nasty way would be to manipulate the url using $location and ... ugh ... , I'm sorry I just gagged